# Conjugacy classes with linking number 1 in the complement of a knot?

Tags: group-theory, geometric-topology, knot-theory

Let $K$ be a knot in $S^3$ and let $lk: \pi_1(S^3 - K) \to H_1(S^3-K;\mathbb{Z})$ denote the abelianization map.  Let $1 \in H_1(S^3-K;\mathbb{Z})$ denote a choice of generator.

Is it possible that there are multiple conjugacy classes in $\pi_1(S^3-K)$ that are taken to $1$ by $lk$?

For $K$ the unknot, $lk$ is an isomorphism so certainly not, but I imagine in general we have infinitely many conjugacy classes sent to $1$? I'm afraid I am just bad at proving that things are not conjugate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have an example where multiple conjugacy classes are sent to $1$.

Take $K$ the trefoil knot, its knot group $\pi_1(S^3 - K) \cong B_3$ the braid knot (one can use Wirtinger presentation to see it).
So $B_3 =<a,b \ | \ aba=bab >$ therefore $a$ and $b$ are conjugated (by element $ba$). Thus $lk(a)=lk(b)=1$.

But $b^2 a^2 b^{-3}$ is not conjugated to $b$. I do not knot how to prove it, but Sagemath does, since this code:

```
B.<a,b>=BraidGroup(3)
print (b^2*a^2*b^(-3)).is_conjugated(b)
```

return:

```
false
```

Since $lk(b^2 a^2 b^{-3})=2+2-3=1$, then you have two different conjugacy classes that maps to $1$.

I am sorry that I used a Sage algorithm blackbox in this answer, but I couldn't figure out how exactly one proves that two elements are not conjugated. I think it is a non trivial matter and it is called [Conjugacy Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_problem). But fortunately there is an algorithm for Knot Groups (the problem is soluble as shown in this [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/004093839390026R) ).

Comment: Thanks! I'll hit you with the bounty although I was hoping for a more concrete reason.  Probably can look at the image of that element in some finite group and see that it is not conjugate to the conjugacy class that the meridians go to?  Or look at the image in a matrix group and take the trace...

Comment: Well yes, I think you are right. In my example, it should be easier to see thing in some representation of $B_3$, like LKB representation, we hence just have to check if matrices (with coefficient in $\mathbb{Z}[x^{\pm 1},y^{\pm 1}]$) aren't similar.
But in the general case, I don't know what could be a Knot Group representation to work with and check 'non conjugacy'. It would be better if it was faithful I think.